# DragDrop text from browser to TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, safari

I'm trying to drag and drop some text from a webpage to a textbox on a Winform.  All works as expected from MS Edge, Firefox Opera and Chrome but not IE11 or Safari.  The brief code I am using on the DragOver event is:

```
 private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
        if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text, false))
        {
            textBox1.Text = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        }
 }
```

It seems like the DataFormat from IE and Safari is not Text, but I can't figure out what it is.

Of course, it might be a browser thing not letting me drag text out.

Any ideas what's causing my issue?

Thanks,

J.

Comment: Hi, IE has security restrictions for copying data to the clipboard and dragging of content between separate windows. By default domains in the Internet zone prompt for access to the clipboard/memory and disable drag/drop. Other browsers like safari have site by site security granularity and may or may not be centrally managed with global policies. Can you post your html and javascript to a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to get the data in all available formats from a Drag&Drop operation.
A Browser source works fine (I tested Edge, IE 11 and FireFox).
 

The Source formats are usually passed as strings or as a `MemoryStream`.
You can further adapt it to your context.

**UPDATE:**
Rebuilt the main Class object. It's now more compact and handles more details. Also, I've added a sample VS sample `WinForms` Form to test its results. It's a standard Form that can be included in a VS Project.

Google Drive: [Drag & Drop sample Form](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19otXEBs59m1UfpVIGcdkUoSvMV6V3oiD)

[image: Drag & Drop results C# project]

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


private FileDropResults DD_Results;

public class FileDropResults
{
    public enum DataFormat : int
    {
        MemoryStream = 0,
        Text,
        UnicodeText,
        Html,
        Bitmap,
        ImageBits,
    }

    public FileDropResults() { this.Contents = new List<DropContent>(); }

    public List<DropContent> Contents { get; set; }

    public class DropContent
    {
        public object Content { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public DataFormat Format { get; set; }
        public string DataFormatName { get; set; }
        public List<Bitmap> Images { get; set; }
        public List<string> HttpSourceImages { get; set; }
    }
}

private void TextBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    GetDataFormats(e.Data);
}

private void TextBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void GetDataFormats(IDataObject Data)
{
    DD_Results = new FileDropResults();
    List<string> _formats = Data.GetFormats(false).ToList<string>();

    foreach (string _format in _formats)
    {
        FileDropResults.DropContent CurrentContents = new FileDropResults.DropContent() 
        { DataFormatName = _format };

        switch (_format)
        {
            case ("FileGroupDescriptor"):
            case ("FileGroupDescriptorW"):
            case ("DragContext"):
            case ("UntrustedDragDrop"):
                break;
            case ("DragImageBits"):
                CurrentContents.Content = (MemoryStream)Data.GetData(_format, true);
                CurrentContents.Format = FileDropResults.DataFormat.ImageBits;
                break;
            case ("FileDrop"):
                CurrentContents.Content = null;
                CurrentContents.Format = FileDropResults.DataFormat.Bitmap;
                CurrentContents.Images = new List<Bitmap>();
                CurrentContents.Images.AddRange(
                    ((string[])Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(img => Bitmap.FromFile(img))
                    .Cast<Bitmap>().ToArray());
                break;
            case ("HTML Format"):
                CurrentContents.Format = FileDropResults.DataFormat.Html;
                CurrentContents.Content = Data.GetData(DataFormats.Html, true);
                int HtmlContentInit = CurrentContents.Content.ToString().IndexOf("<html>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                if (HtmlContentInit > 0)
                    CurrentContents.Content = CurrentContents.Content.ToString().Substring(HtmlContentInit);
                CurrentContents.HttpSourceImages = DD_GetHtmlImages(CurrentContents.Content.ToString());
                break;
            case ("UnicodeText"):
                CurrentContents.Format = FileDropResults.DataFormat.UnicodeText;
                CurrentContents.Content = Data.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText, true);
                break;
            case ("Text"):
                CurrentContents.Format = FileDropResults.DataFormat.Text;
                CurrentContents.Content = Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text, true);
                break;
            default:
                CurrentContents.Format = FileDropResults.DataFormat.MemoryStream;
                CurrentContents.Content = Data.GetData(_format, true);
                break;
        }

        if (CurrentContents.Content != null)
        {
            if (CurrentContents.Content.GetType() == typeof(MemoryStream))
            {
                using (MemoryStream _memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ((MemoryStream)CurrentContents.Content).CopyTo(_memStream);
                    _memStream.Position = 0;

                    CurrentContents.Result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(_memStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (CurrentContents.Content.GetType() == typeof(String))
                    CurrentContents.Result = CurrentContents.Content.ToString();
            }
        }
        DD_Results.Contents.Add(CurrentContents);
    }
}

public List<string> DD_GetHtmlImages(string HtmlSource)
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(HtmlSource, @"<img[^>]+src=""([^""]*)""",
                              RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return (matches.Count > 0)
            ? matches.Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(x => x.Groups[1]
                    .ToString()).ToList()
            : null;
}
```

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer, which I am yet to try. However, if the browser isn't releasing the text then there'll be nothing to drop.  I update once I've given it a go.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jason James  I made a (bit heavy) edit. Now it's easier to handle Html images when a Drop includes multiple sources (html text and images). Direct images drops are immediately available (all end up in a List<> Property + some info). HTTP sources are listed but not downloaded..

Comment: @Jason James  I see you have accepted the answer, but, considering the time elapsed, I think you did it out of courtesy. I reviewed the code and, I have to admit, it wasn't easy to understand. Thus, I re-wrote it. The main class should be easier to handle, however it's still complicated. So I prepared a sample Form that can be included in any Winforms project. It's self contained. It should give you a much clearer idea of what it can do. You just need to select any part of an Html page and drop it on one of the two controls that support the Drop. Maybe, let me know what you think about it.