# How can I retrieve the drag-drop data from chrome, like Windows Explorer does

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

If I drag an image from Chrome (or Firefox) onto the Desktop, Windows Explorer (*not IE*) is able to save the file.

However, if I attempt to get the Bitmap from the `System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject`, there is no Bitmap data available for Chrome (and only DIB from Firefox).

So riddle me this, how is Explorer able to get the actual image from Chrome/Firefox, when it's not available in `IDataObject`? Does Microsoft have a undocumented feature the only Windows can use to extract the image data? **I know how to get the image via the URI, or the FileDrop tempfile (see below). The question is "how to get the served file", like Explorer does.**

Some things to note:

1. The JPEG dropped onto the Desktop is identical (md5sum) to the one served, plus EXIF data is preserved, so it can't be converting the DIB (if present) to a JPEG.
2. The Image is behind an authenticated session, so Explorer can't be fetching the file by the URL.
3. Both browsers provide `DragImageBits`, but this isn't the original image (it's too small), plus it's only supposed to be used as an preview when dragging (Explorer does this).
4. Firefox provides a `FileDrop` array which contains a tempfile, but this is a BMP, not a JPEG.

I actually wrote a small app to display `IDataObject` data from Paste/DragDrop events in order to solve this, but to no avail.

Source & binary available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tipstrade/DragDropViewer/releases)

Comment: The dragged image is treates a file drop (goes in your temp folder). If it's a mixed drop (text and images, it could, but its more often treated as a file (http source) download. See this [DragDrop text from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978257/dragdrop-text-from-browser-to-textbox?answertab=active#tab-top). There's also a small project that let's you test the results. The `DragImageBits` is the smaller iconic grayed image used to "animate" the drop.

Answer (score 2):

After reading some comments about the `System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject` class not exposing `IStream` (which I had no idea about), I came across a CodeProject article [Outlook Drag and Drop in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C).

> Mail messages are an issue because the OS call returns an IStorage which is a compound file type, and again, the C# implementation of the **IDataObject lets us down by not handling this type of return, so you get a null**.

So, lifting liberally from that example (I haven't implement `IStorage`, as what I was mainly interested about turned out to be `HGlobal`) I created a set of extension methods that allow me to retrieve the FileContent.

Usage:

```
var fileNames = e.Data.GetFileContentNames();
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
  using (var ms = e.Data.GetFileContent(i)) {
    // Do something with your unadulterated content!
  }
}
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DragDropViewer.ExtensionMethods {
  /// <summary>Helper methods for getting FileContents from DragDrop data.</summary>
  /// <see cref="!:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C"/>
  public static class IDataObjectExtensionMethods {
    /// <summary>Gets the array of FileNames from the FileGroupDescriptors format.</summary>
    public static string[] GetFileContentNames(this System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data) {
      var names = new string[data.GetFileContentCount()];

      if (names.Length != 0) {
        var bytes = data.GetFileGroupDescriptor().ToArray();
        IntPtr fgdPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try {
          fgdPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);

          int offset = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(UInt32));
          int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FILEDESCRIPTORW));

          for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
            var fd = (FILEDESCRIPTORW)Marshal.PtrToStructure(fgdPtr + offset + (i * size), typeof(FILEDESCRIPTORW));
            names[i] = fd.cFileName;
          }

        } finally {
          if (fgdPtr != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(fgdPtr);

        }
      }

      return names;
    }

    /// <summary>Gets the number of files available in the FileGroupDescriptor format.</summary>
    public static int GetFileContentCount(this System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data) {
      // File count is stored as an UInt32 in the FileGroupDescriptor format
      MemoryStream ms = data.GetFileGroupDescriptor();
      if (ms == null) return 0;

      using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ms)) {
        return (int)reader.ReadUInt32(); // Assume this won't overflow!
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets the file content for the specified FileDescriptor index.</summary>
    /// <param name="index">The index of the file content to retrieve.</param>
    public static MemoryStream GetFileContent(this System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data, int index) {
      // As this is indexed, "FileContent" is most likely null, so the COM IDataObject needs to be used
      var comData = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject)data;

      var formatetc = new FORMATETC() {
        cfFormat = (short)DataFormats.GetFormat("FileContents").Id,
        dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT,
        lindex = index,
        ptd = IntPtr.Zero,
        tymed = TYMED.TYMED_ISTREAM | TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL
      };

      var medium = new STGMEDIUM();
      comData.GetData(ref formatetc, out medium);

      switch (medium.tymed) {
        case TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL:
          return data.GetFileContentFromHGlobal(medium);

        case TYMED.TYMED_ISTREAM:
          return data.GetFileContentFromIStream(medium);

        default:
          throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot get FileContent for {medium.tymed} TYMED.");

      }
    }

    private static MemoryStream GetFileContentFromHGlobal(this System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data, STGMEDIUM medium) {
      var innerDataField = data.GetType().GetField("innerData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
      var oldData = (System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject)innerDataField.GetValue(data);

      var getDataFromHGLOBLALMethod = oldData.GetType().GetMethod("GetDataFromHGLOBLAL", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

      return (MemoryStream)getDataFromHGLOBLALMethod.Invoke(oldData, new object[] { "FileContents", medium.unionmember });
    }

    private static MemoryStream GetFileContentFromIStream(this System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data, STGMEDIUM medium) {
      var iStream = (IStream)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(medium.unionmember);
      Marshal.Release(medium.unionmember);

      var iStreamStat = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG();
      iStream.Stat(out iStreamStat, 0);

      var content = new byte[(int)iStreamStat.cbSize];
      iStream.Read(content, content.Length, IntPtr.Zero);

      return new MemoryStream(content);
    }

    private static MemoryStream GetFileGroupDescriptor(this System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data) {
      MemoryStream ms = null;
      if (data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptorW")) {
        ms = (MemoryStream)data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW", true);
      }

      return ms;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct FILEDESCRIPTORW {
      public UInt32 dwFlags;
      public Guid clsid;
      public System.Drawing.Size sizel;
      public System.Drawing.Point pointl;
      public UInt32 dwFileAttributes;
      public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
      public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
      public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
      public UInt32 nFileSizeHigh;
      public UInt32 nFileSizeLow;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
      public String cFileName;
    }
  }
}
```