# Winforms drag-drop difference from Explorer drag-drop?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop, explorer

I have the following code on a Winforms form where I am attempting to implement a Drag and Drop operation, with the Winforms form being the source:

```
Dim filesToDrag As String() = {"\\Path\to\file"}
Me.DoDragDrop(New DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, filesToDrag), DragDropEffects.All)
```

This code works fine for dragging the file from Winforms onto the Desktop (Explorer).  However, I can't drag the file from Winforms to a program that would normally be a target such as Notepad.

I can drag the file from Winforms to the desktop, then from the desktop to Notepad, etc.  I can also drag the file from it's original path in Explorer to Notepad.

Any idea what my Winforms is doing differently behind the scenes than a normal Explorer drag that causes this not to work?

Comment: I've posted this test project for another question: [DragDrop text from browser to TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978257/dragdrop-text-from-browser-to-textbox?answertab=active#tab-top). In C#, but the code doesn't change much. It's built to test Drag&Drop mixed content (Text and Images) from a WebBrowser to a WinForms app. You can use it to see the difference between a simple FileDrop with just a file path and a shell Drag operation. Drag a file from Explorer and see the result. It's built to handle Image files. It will crash for a other files. It's supposed to, for testing.

Comment: Thanks Jimi.  I downloaded the test form and tried it, but for some reason it won't accept a drop from any file type I try.  I may try to sort out the code and get it to work, as something like this would be helpful to determine the differences.

Comment: Why would't it accept the drop? It's coded to accept all DataFormats. Try adding your files(s) to a [StringCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection) and then add the collection using `[DataObject].SetFileDropList([StringCollection])` With a DataObject previously initialized. You could also post the whole code related to this operation. It would be more clear what's happening then.